# runtime error in thread in c++

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

Getting runtime error in thread, error is "Unhandled exception at 0x0043e98e in clientCheck.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x025042c4".

```
 //create thread in cpp file 
        CreateThread(NULL,0,stayConnectedAtClient,this,0,NULL);
        //thread definition in header file 
        static unsigned long __stdcall stayConnectedAtClient(void *i_socketTransPortClient){
                    ((SocketTransportClient*)i_socketTransPortClient)->stayConnectedThread();
                         return 0;
                }

        //thread function defination in cpp file
        void RMLThinTransport::SocketTransportClient::stayConnectedThread()
        {
            Sleep(20000);
            OutputDebugStringW(L"this is stayconnected thread");
            while(m_tryToConnect) // get error here, not getting value of m_tryToConnect it is Boolean and declared in class.  
            {
                if(!m_isConnected) // m_isConnected value is also not updated even if it is changed by other function
                {
                    break;
                }
                /* sleep for period of time given in configuration file */
                Sleep(m_stayConnected);
                if(!m_allreadyConnected)
                {
                    bool isConnect=Connect();
                    if(isConnect)
                    {
                        m_allreadyConnected=true;
                    }
                    OutputDebugStringW(L"isConnect false");
                }
            }
        }
```

all values are updated in method disconnect.

```
bool RMLThinTransport::SocketTransportClient::disconnect()
{
    m_isConnected=false;
    m_tryToConnect=false;
    notifyUserConnected(m_isConnected); 
    if(m_socketClient!=INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        shutdown(m_socketClient,SD_BOTH);
        closesocket(m_socketClient);
        m_socketClient=INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
    Sleep(3000);
    return false;
}


bool RMLThinTransport::SocketTransportClient::Connect()
{
    try
    {
        m_socketClient = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
        if(m_socketClient==INVALID_SOCKET){
            int lastError;
            lastError=WSAGetLastError();
            SocketExceptions exceptionInOpenSocket;
            exceptionInOpenSocket.detectErrorOpenSocket(&lastError);
            throw exceptionInOpenSocket;
        }
    }
    catch(SocketExceptions& i_exceptionInOpenSocket)
    {
        throw i_exceptionInOpenSocket;
        return false;
    }

    memset(&m_SocketAddressIn,0,sizeof(m_SocketAddressIn));
    m_SocketAddressIn.sin_family=AF_INET;
    m_SocketAddressIn.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(m_ccIPAddress);
    m_SocketAddressIn.sin_port=htons(m_portNumber);
    try
    {
        if(SOCKET_ERROR==connect(m_socketClient,(SOCKADDR *)&m_SocketAddressIn,sizeof(m_SocketAddressIn)))
        {
            m_allreadyConnected=false;
            int lastErrorCode=WSAGetLastError();
            SocketExceptions exceptionInConnection;
            exceptionInConnection.detectErrorConnect(&lastErrorCode);
            throw exceptionInConnection;

        }
        else
        {
            setConnected(true);
            m_allreadyConnected=true;
            if(m_evesdropString!=""){
                char* charbuf=new char[m_evesdropString.size()+1];
                std::copy(m_evesdropString.begin(),m_evesdropString.end(),charbuf);
                charbuf[m_evesdropString.size()]='\0';
                int iResult=send(m_socketClient,charbuf,strlen(charbuf),0);
                memset(charbuf,0x00,sizeof(charbuf));
            }
            CreateThread(NULL,0,receiveClientData,this,0,NULL);
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(SocketExceptions& i_exceptionInConnection)
    {
        shutdown(m_socketClient,SD_BOTH);
        closesocket(m_socketClient);
        m_socketClient=INVALID_SOCKET;
        this->exceptionOccurred(EST_EXCEPTIONINCONNECT);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

so please can anyone tell me what is the problem.?

Comment: where are you using locks to prevent races?

Comment: ok, i edit my question i will put connect method also.

Comment: Have you tried running it with a debugger, seeing which line the error arises? Then read the variable values in that context see which ones are wrong?

Comment: i am not getting value of m_tryToConnect using debugger. so there may be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a good idea to use `CreateThread()` directly from C++ code. You should rather use `_beginthreadex()` to initialize C++ runtime environment for you thread (TLS variables and other stuff).

Comment: This is largely no longer true.